# JSON decode error while sending post request during testing

Tags: json, django, django-testing

I am trying to test my signup url. When I do the following it gives me an error.

tests.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.test import TestCase
# Create your tests here.
class SignUpTest(TestCase):
    def test_createAccount(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        response = self.client.post('/signup/', {'username': 'test_username', 'password': 'test_password',"email":"example@gmail.com", "confirm_password":"test_password", "type_of_user":"1", "first_name":"john", "last_name":"doe"})
        print response
        self.assertIs(response, {"success":True})
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akashtomar/.virtualenvs/wingify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/akashtomar/.virtualenvs/wingify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/akashtomar/.virtualenvs/wingify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/akashtomar/.virtualenvs/wingify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/akashtomar/Desktop/repo/onlinestore/portal/views.py", line 20, in signup
    data = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/akashtomar/.virtualenvs/wingify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 548, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/Users/akashtomar/.virtualenvs/wingify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 350, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/Users/akashtomar/.virtualenvs/wingify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 416, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/Users/akashtomar/.virtualenvs/wingify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 501, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/akashtomar/.virtualenvs/wingify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/akashtomar/.virtualenvs/wingify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/akashtomar/.virtualenvs/wingify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/akashtomar/.virtualenvs/wingify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/akashtomar/Desktop/repo/onlinestore/portal/views.py", line 20, in signup
    data = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from portal.views import *
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^signup/',signup,name='signup'),
    url(r'^addproduct/',addProduct,name='addproduct'),
    url(r'^logout/',logout,name='logout'),
    url(r'^login/',login,name='login'),
    url(r'^deleteproduct/',deleteProduct,name='deleteproduct'),
    url(r'^search/',search,name='search'),
    url(r'^update/',update,name='update'),
    url(r'^getproduct/',getProduct,name='getproduct'),
]
```

This is my views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def signup(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        data = request.body
        data = json.loads(data)
        username = data["username"]
        email = data["email"]
        password = data["password"]
        confirm_password = data["confirm_password"]
        first_name = data["first_name"]
        last_name = data["last_name"]
        type_of_user = data["type_of_user"]

        if password!=confirm_password:
            return JsonResponse({"success":False,"reason":"passwords don't match"})
        user = User(username=username,email=email,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_active=True
        try:
            user.save()
        except:
            return JsonResponse({"success":False,"reason":"user already exists"})

        user_a=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user_a is not None:
            if user_a.is_active:
                log(request,user_a)
        else:
            return HttpResponse({"success":False,"reason":"internal db error"});

        access_token = str(uuid.uuid4().get_hex())
        try:
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            at = AccessToken(token_value=access_token)
            at.save()
            UserProfile(user=user,type_of_user=int(type_of_user),access_token=at).save()
        except:
            return JsonResponse({"success":False,"reason":"internal error"})
        return JsonResponse({"success":True,"access_token":access_token})
```

P.S I have tried using `json.loads` and `json.dump` and also tried using double quotes instead of single quotes. It is not working.

Comment: try to replace single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: @latsha Tried that. Still doesn't work. Also tried dumping using json.

Comment: which django version do you using?

Comment: Please provide full traceback of exception along with your `urls.py` which contains `/signup/` pattern and `views.py` containing view for it. Also show your real code for test case (if above code in question is just you make up to explain the error).

Comment: @latsha django 1.11

Comment: @AamirAdnan Please check my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is coming from signup view at line `data = json.loads(data)`.
In order to access the `POST` data you can simply access it by using `request.POST`:

```
data = request.POST
```

So remove these lines and replace with above line of code:

```
data = request.body
data = json.loads(data)
```

Or try (as figured out via discussion):

```
response = self.client.post('/signup/', json.dumps(my_data), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: I needed request.body since I was sending this data through a mobile device. The POST request data was not coming in request.POST

Comment: Try to print `request.body` what you get? Please don't post sensitive information such as real user name and password or email.

Comment: I get a json object of the data sent as parameters in POST request. Everything is working fine when I send data through POSTMAN or mobile device. It breaks while testing.

Comment: try this in test `response = self.client.post('/signup/', json.dumps(my_data), content_type='application/json')`

Comment: Explicitly setting `content_type` works? Let me know so that I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes, it needs to set the `content_type` explicitly.

Comment: If I wanted to have Authorization as a parameter to the request, will this be the correct format? `response = self.client.post('/addproduct/', json.dumps(my_data), content_type='application/json',Authorization=self.access_token)`

Answer (score 0):

if you get error for printing (using) response.json()
instead of response.json() use response.data

```
response = self.client.get(url, data)
print(response.json()) # if cause 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError', use response.data
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with it. Use dict() instead of json.

```
data = dict(request.POST)['checkedbox']
result = list(map(int, data))
```

Comment: Add more detail for your answer please, explain more why this fix ?

Comment: HI! Honestly, I was receiving error while using `json.loads(request.body)` , other methods as well didn't work for me (I searched similar type of issues on  StackOverflow). Then I just got an idea to use `dict()`. And to get value out of hast table we can either use `.get()` or  `[]`. Then we need to convert those values to int (as they're id to be used for filtering further), and by default they're string as they come from url.